# How can I create button with html to symlink file in perl?

Tags: perl, symlink

I'm facing a problem in perl I'm work on script actually symlink tool so I tried to create a button
named symlink to symlink a file called /etc/passwd 
so how I call but these together

```
$target="/etc/passwd";
$distension ="1.txt";

$symlink = symlink($target,$distension);

if($symlink == 1) {print " distension symlink created successfully";}

else {print "cannot symlink File $distension Already Exists ";}
```

---

```
<button value="" name="symlink" type="button"
onclick="alert('symlink created successfully ^_^')">symlink</button>
```

So what I want is when i click symlink button that will happened
and sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

The Perl program needs to run in a Web server or as a Web server. Example:

**app.psgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/env plackup
use strict;
use warnings;
use Plack::Request qw();
use HTTP::Status qw(
    HTTP_OK HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
);

my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    if ('POST' eq $req->method) {
        my $target = '/etc/passwd';
        my $distension = '1.txt';
        if (symlink $target, $distension) {
            return $req->new_response(
                HTTP_OK, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [
                    'distension symlink created successfully'
                ]
            )->finalize;
            print ;
        } else {
            return $req->new_response(
                HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [
                    "could not symlink <$target> to <$distension>: $!"
                ]
            )->finalize;
        }
    } else {
        return $req->new_response(HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)->finalize;
    }
};
```

The HTML form needs to cause a POST request to the Web server.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000">
    <input type="submit" value="create symlink">
</form>
```